# C++/NetBeans/CygWin/Windows - unresolved includes inside <iostream>

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, iostream

I always get the error in the title. I tried 7.3.1 and 7.4 of netbeans and spent hours downloading the packages from cygwin over and over again.

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the title of your project :-D

Comment: Are other headers working, e.g. `#include <string>`? And is `stddef.h` somewhere in your cygwin path existing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed!
Just remembered i made this question, i was pretty upset trying everything. The solution is simple: cygwin 64 bit isn't working. 32 bit does. 
So if someone finds this via google, just use 32 bit version of cygwin!

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause are the blanks in your path (before the x86), this can make some trouble. Please test a cygwin path without any blanks inside, the best place to install is outside of windows program directories.

Spaces in paths are interpreted as word separators, you can escape those using `\`, but that's not available in this scenario.